# How to output strings with leading tab using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, piping

In PowerShell, say I have a collection of string objects:

```
'a b c'.split()
```

I can pipe these to an output stream:

```
'a b c'.split() | Write-Host
```

So I get "a", "b" and "c" on separate lines.

**Now: how do I change this so that each line (string) has a leading tab character?**

I know tab is represented by `t so my first attempt was this:

```
'a b c'.split() | Write-Host "`t$_"
```

This gives me the error:

> Write-Host : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and 
>   its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Okay, so let's take out the tab and just use $_ which I thought represented the 'current' object that was being returned by the pipeline.

```
'a b c'.split() | Write-Host $_
```

Same error:

> Write-Host : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and 
>   its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

There is obviously something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding here, so I'm hoping someone can point out what that is! Also, ignore the use of `Write-Host`: I'm just using it for illustration purposes, my intention is to pipe to `Write-Verbose` ultimately.

Comment: The `$_` variable is create by certain cmdlets, it doesn't just exist by default when passing things down the pipeline. That's why using `for-each` works. The `for-each` cmdlet create the `$_` variable and then invokes your script/expression.

Comment: @Sean Ah, okay, that makes more sense now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
'a b c'.split() | foreach {write-host "`t$_"}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Although I'm still not sure why $_ works on the pipeline with some cmdlets and not others.

Comment: $_ is foreach, where  etc when you use {}    detail here http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_dollar_variable.htm

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  'a b c'.split() | %{Write-Host "`t$_"}
```

or short

```
  'a b c'.split() | %{"`t$_"}
```

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
   'a b c'.Split() | select @{N="Value";E={"`t$_"}}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14055066)

Comment: the question is "Now: how do I change this so that each line (string) has a leading tab character?", my code provide an answer to this question...